# How to take image or file to a variable in vue?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to add image to my database with diffrent datas in same time. I don't want to hold img data in diffrent place. Then I want to add image data to database in base64 format but I can't find to get image data from the form. I mean ,how can I reach to added image in vue?

Comment: If you're using Vuetify you could to use a file input: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/file-inputs/

Comment: I already know file input but I don't know how to take that image data to a variable

Comment: `v-model` should do the trick; it's what I use. It wil return a variable of the `File` type. Here's an example: https://github.com/haroldo-ok/vcs-game-maker/blob/master/src/views/Project.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
toDataURL(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function () {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function () {
      callback(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.open("GET", url);
  xhr.responseType = "blob";
  xhr.send();
},
readFile() {
  this.example = this.$refs.file.files[0];
  if (
    this.example.name.includes(".png") ||
    this.example.name.includes(".jpg")
  ) {
    this.image = true;
    this.preview = URL.createObjectURL(this.example);

    this.toDataURL(this.preview, (dataUrl) => {
      var imgBase64 = dataUrl.split("data:image/png;base64,");
      this.imageData = imgBase64[1];
      console.log(this.imageData);
     
    });
  } else {
    this.image = false;
  }
},
```

the exit will be base64 in string